# Tunnel LoL through firewall

Tags: tunnel

I would like to tunnel a game called League of Legends through a firewall blocking UDP. What I managed so far is to set up a TCP tunnel and a connection is made but I can only browse the net, and the game won't work so far. The problem is that the game has more than one server to connect to, and I don't know which one is used. I found on a lot of sites that you can directly forward a port using netcat but that is not a big help here.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're exactly trying to do. What does the TCP tunnel go to? If the game only accepts UDP, and you can't get UDP through the firewall, you're going to need something outside the firewall to send the UDP packets to the game. Is there a machine outside the firewall you control? Or do you have control over the game servers and want to add some capability to them?

Comment: One thing you can do is set up a TCP-based VPN. VPNs will typically encapsulate *all* protocols (anything that's based on IPv4 or IPv6) to the remote host. Try OpenVPN.

Comment: I have a server running a TCP tunnel, and a Client on the remote PC. Proxifier passes packets from apps to the Client app.

Comment: Just so you know, questions concerning circumventing security typically are not received well on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

I used to play this from College, and we used HotSpotShield.  I know it's added overhead, but at least it worked.

Any kind of tunnel/proxy solution I tried never seemed to work either.  I tried stuff like TOR project.

Comment: I'm assuming it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [UDPTunnel](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~lennox/udptunnel/) or may be some instructions on how to [forward UDP over ssh](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-perform-udp-tunneling-through-ssh-connection.html)

If you are running mac or linux the above should work, however if you are running windows I may be of less help. My first guess would be to use a linux box as a firewall so I could redirect the traffic as I please with tools above.